# Peculiar error in dplyr filter

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, subset

I am working through Hadley Wickham's 2015 ggplot book. In it, there is a line of code (the ggplot2 package is already loaded):

```
presidential <- subset(presidential, start > economics$date[1])
```

and it works fine. I tried replacing subset with filter as in:

```
library(dplyr)
presidential <- filter(presidential, start > economics$date[1])
```

and I get the error:

```
Error in `>.default`(start, x) : 
  comparison (6) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

If the comparison is incorrect, should it also not affect subset?

Comment: Check the str of `economics$date`.  Is it a list or vector?  If it is a list `economics$date[[1]]`

Comment: My attempt worked alright. Is it possible it's something to do with locally defined variables? Maybe try clearing the environment and running it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem. If I explicitly specify dplyr:: as below, then it works:

```
presidential <- dplyr::filter(presidential, start > economics$date[1])
```

This means that some other filter function was overriding the one from dplyr.

In the code that I had posted earlier, I had indicated the library(dplyr) line just before the line of code that I thought was causing the problem, but in reality, dplyr had been loaded earlier as part of my startup script.

It looks like the stats package which also has a filter function was loaded after dplyr was loaded (because dplyr was in my startup script) and hence stats::filter masked dplyr::filter.

I really ought to have checked this first before posting, but it does highlight something about the impacts that loading packages in the startup scripts can have. The other tricky point is that in this situation we do not get any messages about the masking that has occurred.